# What is the alternative for IN sql operator in LINQ for string field?

Tags: c#, sql, linq

Please find the example below which I am trying to achieve.

```
List<string> list = new List<string>() { "Test", "Test1", "Test2","Test","Test1" };

SQL = select * from table_name
     where column_name IN ("Test","Test1");<br/>
output = { "Test","Test1","Test","Test1"}

LINQ= from x in list where list.Contains("Test","Test1") select x

output = { "Test", "Test1", "Test2","Test","Test1" }
```

Contains Does not do an exact match.
How can we get the same output as SQL IN operator with string list in LINQ?

Thanks

Comment: you could use `Contains` or `Any` it should give you similar results.

Comment: The LINQ statement is not what you intend it to be. `where list.Contains("Test","Test1")` is always true.

Answer (score 1):

You're using Contains incorrectly (and indeed, your example code doesn't compile). Instead, declare a set that you wish to match against and use Contains on that set, like this:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>() { "Test", "Test1", "Test2","Test","Test1" };

var match = new HashSet<string>() { "Test", "Test1" };

var result = from x in list where match.Contains(x) select x;
```

Result:

```
Test
Test1
Test
Test1
```

Comment: Note you could create `match` inline (thought not very concisely as a `HashSet`) without performance penalty (in this small example): `new[] { "Test", "Test1" }.Contains(x)`

Comment: Yep, indeed I usually do that. I thought the separate declaration would make it easier to follow.

Comment: I agree it is easier to follow, but perhaps a bit less like the SQL.

Answer (score 0):

A similar approach to Eric's answer but using join:

```
var list = new List<string>() { "Test", "Test1", "Test2","Test","Test1" };
var match = new HashSet<string>() { "Test", "Test1" };

var results = from x in list
              join y in match on x equals y
              select x;
```